# inflating views android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I have this main.xml layout which has a fixed header and footer. The body content has to change based on the parameters received.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/main_view">
    <com.HeaderView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderView"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.FooterView
        android:id="@+id/FooterView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/BodyView"
        android:layout_below="@id/HeaderView"
        android:layout_above="@id/FooterView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Based on the below conditions I need to load the BodyView in the main.xml.

```
If parameter == Apple 
  then load layout AppleView in the BodyView
if parameter == Bat
  then load layout BatView in the BodyView
```

I have AppleView and BatView xml layout defined. Could somebody please guide me as to how I can load either of the views and set/get values into/from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of inflating, hope this is what you need.

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp, null);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.glavenfrejm);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parametri = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parametri.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        rl.addView(v, parametri);
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am still not able to figure out how do I use this piece of code. Could you please elaborate

Comment: After each test(after each if)  you do this(do the inflating of the layout.